# If else statement issue with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Ive been trying to put the following items into a If / Else statement with out much luck, anyone able to quickly point me in the right direction...

**If** ($link_image is active then display the code... )

```
            <div class="qodef-e-quote-image">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($link_image, 'full');  ?>
            </div>
```

**Else** (display the following)

```
    <span class="qodef-e-icon"><?php echo webon_return_svg_link(); ?>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: `isset` may be want you want: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php . you may need to define what you mean by "is active".

Comment: Side note: Your `<span>` is missing its closing tag `</span>`.